# Restframework APi response hide

Tags: python, django, api, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have built an application using python django rest framework and Vue js.
The rest framework link is something similar like this `198.123.1.1:8001/test` i am using this link to get records in Vuejs.

when i call this link generally `198.123.1.1:8001/test`

```
GET /test/

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "test_id": 11,
        "test_n_key": "as-all-1",
        }
```

i am getting the below response now i want to hide this response to outside world and what will be the better way to do it.

1)I don't want to show this url to outside world.
2)when someone is calling this from browser other than application it should not show it

Comment: The DRF will only return the fields you specified in your serializer. Anything that you don't want exposed, just remove from the serializer.

Comment: i can understand i need all the fields only thing is i want to hide when someone from out side call this its should not show them values.

Comment: Add CORS rules to it and whitelist the origins that are allowed to see this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

if the API is exposed to the outside world you cant hide it, add an authentication to the API and prevent external request.

Answer (score 0):

Add authentication and CORS:

[CORS-Headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/)

[Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)